# Fried transistor identification help

Tags: transistors, inverter, surface-mount

I know this is sometimes a contentious question but this this one isn't marked with anything I recognise ... See image below there are 4 transistors, 2 marked "NY" and 2 marked "MY". No other visible marking. I haven't yet desoldered to test but at least one has let out the bad smoke so not sure how much I'll be able to tell anyway.

Both pairs have collectors connected to each other, and emitter of each MY appear to be hooked to base of each NY as a Darlington pair. They're fed off an optocoupler.

This board drives a bunch of power mosfets, some of which have also let out the bad smoke but thankfully are marked up. This is part of a chunky LF inverter.

Many thanks in advance for any light you might shed, or flame away if appropriate ;)

[image]

Comment: The SMD codebook is a good resource: http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm

Answer (score 2):

Unless you happen to recognize the product codes NY and MY, it will be hard to know what exactly those transistors are.

However, they look to be in a SOT-89 package.  NY and MY are probably the NPN/PNP complements of each other.  Maybe some are working enough to be able to tell which is NY and which is MY.

If you know the maximum voltage they have to withstand, you can probably replace with a reasonable NPN/PNP complementary pair that come in SOT-89 package.

That all said, replacing these parts may not do anything except blow up the new parts.  You have to fix *all* the problems before attempting replacements.  One bad part can take out others.  You said there are multiple failed parts.  These probably all got that way due to one single original failure.

That board is a mess, and it doesn't look due to burnt parts.  The black goo around the top left transistor doesn't look right for a part that blew up.  It looks like serious crud got onto the board, like maybe from a leaking battery.  The crud could have caused leakage paths, which may have been the original cause of the failures.  The board itself may be toast.

It is probably cheaper to just toss this board and move on, unless you value your time at pennies per hour.

Answer (score 2):

[NY appears to be a 2SA1213 PNP transistor.](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/ny)

[MY appears to be the 2SC2873 NPN transistor, which is complementary to the 2SA1213](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/my)

Replacing the transistors without first finding and fixing the real cause won't do you much good - the new ones will just burn out as well.

Looks like there's some hot melt glue on the lower transistors.  There was probably some on the upper ones as well, which would explain the nasty burned gunk around the burned out part.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys, links spot on. Yes it is hot melt glue burned on. As to root cause, condensation might have been one factor. I'm hoping to clean then seal (varnish?) the controller board to reduce that problem. The inverter had been driving an inductive load for a couple of years, could have been just one motor stall too many. It looks like this driver board was designed to be sacrificial so guessing this failure mode is not uncommon. To replace the parts is not a major expense, and I don't have much hope of diagnosing much else with just my trusty multimeter, so worth a shot, no?